# Is this considered as kufr or may be exempted

Tags: hadith, sunnah, shirk, kufr

Assalamu alaikum last day in Google I found that a famous  person is not a member of ahlu sunnah , so I was shocked told about this to my mother and my aunt , now I am scared is not a member of ahlu sunnah is synonymous as calling him kafir if yes , is this an act of kufr. I don't intend to commit kufr or I don't intend to call he / she as kafir , and also I don't know the meaning of ahlu sunnah it was surely unintentional , at that time I thought ahlu sunnah was some course for becoming scholars or something
Is it considered as kufr please mention it is kufr or not
Please answer as soon as possible please

Comment: Ahlus Sunnah wal Jama'ah basically means they who follow the sunnah of Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ). Kafir is someone who close themselves from the truth (Islam). If you have waswas that you spread the wrong information about someone, then tell your family that you might be wrong about that famous person, or if you know the truth then say the truth. And Allah knows best.

Comment: Please mention is that kufr or not I am stressed

Comment: You mean, if YOU are kufr or not? Insha Allah, you shouldn't be kufr (And Allah knows best).  I do not know if calling someone not apart of ahlus sunnah is kufr or not. But even if it is, then verily Allah forgives you for what you did by mistake. However, my advice is do not accuse someone of something (unless it's confirmed). Next time do not tell an information that isn't confirmed. Try to tell your mother and aunt again that you might be wrong about that someone. And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Proclaiming or pronouncing `takfir` upon anybody is not easy. It needs strong evidence, to say the least. One must, in general, refrain from it.